# Flask render_template context is None within a Blueprint

Tags: python, flask

I'm relatively new to Flask, but I'm already finding the need to use Blueprints. However, in my Blueprint, I'm trying to render a template, but getting an error.

When hooked up as a WSGI application (on Dreamhost), the render_template function returns this error:

```
File ".../app/ui/__init__.py", line 95, in index
response = make_response(render_template('index.html', **data))

File ".../flask/templating.py", line 123, in render_template
ctx.app.update_template_context(context)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'
```

However, when I call the app.py directly in debug mode it works perfectly! (below)

```
python app/app.py
```

In app.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

**EDIT:** Rendering template:

```
@ui_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@ui_blueprint.route('/home', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    data = {
        'title': 'Index'
    }
    response = make_response(render_template('index.html', **data))
    return response
```

**EDIT 2:** `ctx` is:

- `None` in the WSGI app case
- `<RequestContext 'http://aaa.bbb.com:5000/' [GET] of __init__>` in the direct call case

Any ideas how I might fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: check `ctx` object in your code,, what does it have, also show the part of code where you create this object..

Comment: You need to use Request Context here. Read this http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/reqcontext/

Comment: @codegeek Yes, the template should be using Request Context. However, how do I ensure that it gets passed to render_template in this instance?

Comment: I discovered an issue with my environment that was leading to this problem. If Jinja isn't installed properly, then it can cause all sorts of problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up Flask, make sure that **all dependencies are installed correctly**. That's the problem in this case.

If running on mod_wsgi, also make sure that any reads or writes are directed to the proper location; otherwise, the app make work when run using `app.run()` but the paths change when using Apache.

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail please? I have the same problem, but everything seems to be installed correctly

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are importing all the right modules:

`from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response, request, Response`

And you may want to create a wrapper for your view.